# Can a zipcode input be validated worldwide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I found this regex

```
var zipCodePattern = /^\d{5}$|^\d{5}-\d{4}$/;
```

That won't validate: 12345, but it does validate 07179.  I need to be sure that it would work worldwide, would it?  If not, does it exist?

Comment: Does it really not validate 12345? It looks like it should match the first part of the regex... Also what do you mean by does it work worldwide? Not all countries have an equivalent of zipcode in that format (eg in the UK the equivalent (a postcode) might be something like SW10 3AT). however if you tried to validate a US zipcode in the UK then it would still validate... I have seen things before that refuse zipcodes in format other than 12345 even when they offer options for different countries. Definitely don't be that person. ;-)

Comment: Nope http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes (also note that at least Ireland has no equivalent system)

Comment: @AlexK.: That would be a **giant** regex.

Comment: ZIP code is a U.S.P.S. term (Zone Improvement Plan). Are you asking for a regex that will validate ANY country's postal code or just a U.S. ZIP code?

Comment: i was asking fist, and i see now is not posible; so question is now; what shall we do? just check is not empty?

Answer (score 4):

No, in some countries(India, for eg.), the Zip Code is of 6 digits and in some others, it might be entirely different with spaces also. Your expression should support that too.